# How do I disable "last pressed" Button state in Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap `Button` component in my React application.

[image: Normal]

The default `Button` has a special appearance after it was pressed and the mouse cursor is already out of it:

[image: last pressed]

This appearance is changed to normal after any click. How do I disable this feature without disturbing any other states (pressed, mouse over, normal) of Bootstrap `Button`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are referring to the blue border. This is the outline on the :focus state.

try this in your css:

```
.btn:focus {
  outline:none;
}
```

for colour try (success btn example):

```
.btn-success:focus {
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  border-color: #4cae4c; 
}
```

Comment: Not only `border`. As you see, the second picture is many ways different from the first one. I think, there may be a special attribute which disables this state.

Comment: note that the :focus and the :link state may cause that effect also

Answer (score 1):

Hiding the focus state of buttons is a bad idea. Hitting the space/enter key whilst a clickable element has focus is the same as clicking it. A user should be able tonknow that. You're better off using script to `blur()` it or move focus to another element.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the @Brad response, maybe you can try to switch the class of the button after click with other of the button clases from bootstrap.

[Check the Bootstrap Button documentation](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/buttons/)